# Python socket loop does not break

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I created socket for two PC, one is Raspberry Pi and the other one is my laptop. I just connected two then I send string to test the connection. If I send a character "q" from the RPi, my PC should break out of the loop and close the connection but it does not. The part `print("Listening")` is still running. Why? See code below.

```
import socket
import time

# IP address of this PC.
TCP_IP = '192.168.137.1'

# Port.
TCP_PORT = 5005

# Size of buffer.
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

# Create a socket, connect and listen to it.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connection address:', addr)

while 1:
    print("Listening")
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    data = data.decode()

    if data=='q':
        break

    if  data: 
        print ("Received data:", data)
        # Echo back. 
        conn.send(data.encode())

    time.sleep(1)

print("It breaks.") 
conn.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending 'q', and not 'q'  + newline? Hard to tell what you are really doing since the code of the client is missing. Code works fine for me if only 'q' is sent.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream oriented protocol. So data transmitted is a stream not a sequence of messages. So when you expect `data` to be `q` it actually is `some_data_sent_before_q_and_finally_q`.

The simplest way to repair the code is to use `if data.endswith('q')` instead of `if data=='q'`. May work and may not depending on how you actually use the connection. For example, this approach may fail with `some_data_sent_before_q` pretty long pause `more_data_and_q` and with `some_data_sent_before_q_and_finally_q_plus_something_else_why_not`.

Little bit more advanced way to solve the problem is to divide the stream into messages with separators - `message_1<separator>message_2<separator>q<separator>`. This method will allow you to treat every message separately.